# Vim: How do I automatically set textwidth=60 when editing a specific file?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have the following line:

> set textwidth=80

However, when editing the files: README-SETUP and README-INSTALL I would like vim to have textwidth set to 60.

I think this can be done for specific file types using autocmd, but how would I do it for specific files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this like so:

```
autocmd BufReadPre README*.txt setlocal textwidth=60
```

Or you could list the files one by one:

```
autocmd BufReadPre README-SETUP setlocal textwidth=60
autocmd BufReadPre README-INSTALL setlocal textwidth=60
```

**EDIT**: As ZyX points out, prefer setlocal over set for options like this you really don't want all buffers having that textwidth for the duration of the session.

Comment: @FunLovinCoder, @Benj Use `:setlocal`, not `:set` for such things, or it will set incorrect textwidth options for all *new* buffers opened after README-*.

Answer (score 7):

You can also add a comment to the top of the file:

```
# vim: textwidth=80
```

You can replace the # by whatever character signifies a comment in your context.

Comment: This can also go at the end of the file...  See `:help modeline`.